# How to swap elements in a matrix 2D array?

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, winforms, multidimensional-array

Hello I have created a program that the user imputs the values of a 2D array 6x6 and show it now I have to make a new metod i guess to rotate the elements from rows 0,2,4 put them in colums 1,3,5 and elements from rows 1,3,5 putting them in colums 0,2,4 than tell how many "M" are in total at the two last rows". can someone tell me how to do that i have no idea. Thanks

This is a photo of my code and another photo how should i change the indexes

[image]

Comment: Don' put code in screenshots. and.. 6x6? i see 4x4

Comment: the 4x4 is just an example of the swaping elements u can clarely see in the code that i have created a 6x6 2d array read first than talk . thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution is written in java hope you get the idea.

```
public class ProgramMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = {
            {0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
            {1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {2,2,2,2,2,2},
            {3,3,3,3,3,3},
            {4,4,4,4,4,4},
            {5,5,5,5,5,5}
        };
    int[][] output = new int [6][6];

    // elements from rows 0,2,4 put them in column 1,3,5 and elements from rows 1,3,5 putting them in column 0,2,4 
    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < output.length; j++) {
            if(i==0||(i%2)==0) {
                output[j][i+1]=arr[i][j];
            }else {
                output[j][i-1]=arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    //Ignore the below code this is only used for printing the matrix
    System.out.println("Input Array");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("\n\nOuput Array");
    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < output.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(output[i][j]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

}
```

[image: output]